# Postgresql server not asking for password for remote connections

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.1

I found my posgresql database server is not asking password for user `postgres` when remote connecting through pgadmin. **I mean this is when I connect to remote database server from my local computer through pgAdmin.**

I did add a password in psql, `ALTER USER postgres PASSWORD 'mypassword'`.

This is my pg_hba.config file:

```
/usr/local/pgsql/bin/psql -qAt -c "show hba_file" | xargs grep -v -E '^[[:space:]]*#'

local   all             all                                     trust
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            md5

host    all             all               0.0.0.0/0             md5
host    all             all             ::1/128                 md5
```

So, I do not quite understand what is happening here.

Can anyone help with this?

Thanks a lot.

**UPDATE:**

If i change:

```
local   all             all                                     trust
```

to

```
local   all             all                                     md5
```

Now, local connections (via SSH) will be asked for password ( wasn't asking for password before.) but remote connections will still connect without a password.

Acutally, I tried connecting to this database server by a rails appliaction from another server, without a password, and the rails server started without a problem.

---

**PUTTING RESULT HERE FOR THE CONVENIENCE**

The real reason of this issue was the `.pgpass` file. Mac stored the password locally in the `.pgpass` file under user home folder. Then every time when user try to login without a password, PostgreSQL will send the password for user.

Official doc [here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/libpq-pgpass.html)

Comment: By default, from what I recall, postgresql is installed without password. You have to add it. I'm sure the docs say how.

Comment: I did add a password in psql, `ALTER USER postgres PASSWORD 'mypassword'`.

Comment: What makes you think you're connecting remotely in PgAdmin? Did you explicitly specify host = `127.0.0.1` or connect from a remote host? If you're connecting over unix socket, with your configuration, no password prompt should be expected because you're using `trust` mode ffor unix sockets (`local`).

Comment: @CraigRinger Im connecting from my local computer to a remote database server.

Comment: Could you provide more detail about how you're connecting remotely? Your initial post led me to believe you meant within your SSH session.

Comment: Did your rails application actually create a connection and communicate with the database? Sometimes, web apps don't establish a connection until it's actually used.

Comment: @jpmc26 yes. I tried the same rails app with a random password, and that connections attempt was failed (told me password authentication was failed). This is so weird. I'm trying to delete all the settings in `pg_hba.conf` and manually adding them one line by one line now. Any other idea of this?

Comment: Could you update the question with a note mentioning the resolution, that the .pgpass file was allowing you to connect seemingly (but not actually) without a password?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Thanks for all the comments and answers ppl!

But the real reason of this issue was the `.pgpass` file. My mac stored the password locally in the `.pgpass` file under my user home folder. Then every time when i try to login without a password, PostgreSQL will send the password for me. 
So that was the issue i was having....

Thanks for all the reply and the comments again!

For more details can refer to [here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/libpq-pgpass.html)

Comment: Thanks for this! I ran into this too. Very helpful.

Answer (score 3):

Reading the documentation at Postgresql.org

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/auth-pg-hba-conf.html

I would suggest that you change the user field with the names of the few users allowed to connect remotely:

```
host    all             john,charles    0.0.0.0/0   scram-sha-256
host    all             john,charles    ::1/128     scram-sha-256
```

Further, for security reasons, I would advice that you look into using `hostssl` and also that you specify the name of the database(s) that can be accessed remotely:

```
hostsll webapp123     john,charles    0.0.0.0/0     scram-sha-256
```

And if the remote access is only from specific computers, specify their static IP addresses (if DHCP is used, use a mask accordingly.)

```
hostsll webapp123     john,charles    1.2.3.4/32    scram-sha-256
```

This way you only compromise database webapp123, to what users john and `charles` can do, and only from computer 1.2.3.4.

As mentioned in the documentation, you can have any number of entries, so if you want to add a test server (i.e. your server at home) then you can add one line so it looks like this:

```
hostsll webapp123     john,charles    1.2.3.4/32    scram-sha-256
hostsll webapp123     henry           home-ip/32    scram-sha-256
```

By not specifying the users, you probably allow any user, including those without passwords and one of them is selected and it works...

Of course, I would strongly advice that you do not name a user who has administration rights in your database unless you also specify his static IP address.